# Showing app.js crashed in vs code terminal after running app.js start command

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been working on one e-commerce website which ahs been build by using MongoDB, Node.js, HTML, Mongoose, Express, Mongo Atlas, and has been hosted on Bluehost web server using GoDaddy domain name. but the website is not live yet!
I've to add new features and make changes on UI but when i try to run command npm init, app.js start it shows app.js crashed. I can you guys suggest me another methods to overcome with this errors.

Comment: npm init is to initialize a fresh project. 
to start there may be a command
npm run start:dev

you can search the command iinside package.json > scripts

Comment: OKAY, WILL BE TRYING IT. IF APP.JS SHOWS APP.JS CRASHED WHAT WILL BE THE RISK FACTORS WILL ARISE WITH CODE FOLDER?